# Check an Array in php of some IDs

Tags: php, arrays, get

I am a absolute beginner in `PHP` and I need some help with my first scipt.

I have an array like this:

```
$ids = array("test1", "testa", "test2", "testv");
```

This is my full code:

```
<?php
$ids = array("test1", "testa", "test2", "testv");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id  == null){$done .= "Wrong ID";}
else if ($id  == $ids[0])
{
$laenge = 8;
for($i=0;$i<$laenge;$i++){$rnd = rand(1,62);
if ($rnd <= 10){$rnd += 47;}else if($rnd <= 36){$rnd += 54;}
else{$rnd += 60; }
$done .= chr($rnd);
}
}?>
```

now I will check the input with an GET variable of the array ( `script.php?id=` ).

at example `script.php?id=test1` <<< Works great because of (`$id  == $ids[0]`) but how can I get it to work that only (all) the variables from my array ($ids) are accepted

at example:

```
script.php?id=test1 = ok
script.php?id=testa = ok
script.php?id=test2 = ok
script.php?id=testv = ok
script.php?id=bla   = Not ok
```

I hope your understand my problem and can help me.
Thank you in advance :)

EDIT:
Thanks for your help but when i use this so

```
<?php
$ids = array("test1", "testa", "test2", "testv");
if(in_array($_GET['id'], $ids) 
{

$laenge = 8;
for($i=0;$i<$laenge;$i++){$rnd = rand(1,62);
if ($rnd <= 10){$rnd += 47;}else if($rnd <= 36){$rnd += 54;}
else{$rnd += 60; }
$gutschein .= chr($rnd);

} else {
echo 'Wrong ID';
}

}?>
```

i become an whitepage, sorry im totay new in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if a value is in a given array.

```
if(in_array($_GET['id'], $ids)) {
  // do stuff
} else {
   echo 'Wrong ID';
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer is it so right? // Look my edit in main post

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method, which likely is what you are looking for.

```
if (in_array($id, $ids)) {
   // Do your stuff when in array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check whether a value is in your array you should use PHPs [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method, as such:

```
else if (in_array($id, $ids))
```

P.S.

In PHP you can use `elseif` instead of `else if`, it's a reserved word for that purpose.